# How can I center my selected accordion item using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scroll

I attempted using `this.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"}), however I was getting very inconsistent results with where the selected item would land. I suspect I need to somehow use scrollTop(), but I am very new to jQuery and am a bit overwhelmed on the different potential solutions.

Here is a working codepen link:
https://codepen.io/boingloings33/pen/JjwWQpE

Thank you.

**Script.js**

```
jQuery(function () {
  $(".head").on("click", function () {
    let isActive = $(this).hasClass("active");

    $(".head").removeClass("active");
    $(".head").parent().find(".content").slideUp(280);
    $(".head").parent().find(".arrow").removeClass("arrow-animate");
    if (isActive === false) {
      $(this).addClass("active");
      $(this).parent().find(".arrow").addClass("arrow-animate");
      $(this).parent().find(".content").slideDown(280);
    }
  });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="accordion" id="accordion-1">
    <div class="head">
      <h2>Number 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br />

  <div class="accordion" id="accordion-2">
    <div class="head">
      <h2>Number 2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br />

  <div class="accordion" id="accordion-3">
    <div class="head">
      <h2>Number 3</h2>   
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br />

  <div class="accordion" id="accordion-4">
    <div class="head">
      <h2>Number 4</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content">     
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br />   
 
  <div class="accordion" id="accordion-5">
    <div class="head">
      <h2>Number 5</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content">     
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
```

**styles.css**

```
body {
  font-family: Lato;
  background: rgb(142, 215, 213);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#content::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

strong {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 56px;
}

.content p {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 800px;
}

.preview-pics {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.3;
  filter: blur(3px);
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}

.preview-pics:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: blur(0);
}

.accordion {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 7px #dbdbdb;
}

.accordion .head {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #563e6e;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.accordion .head:hover,
.accordion .active {
  background-color: #ffe77aff;
}

.accordion .arrow-animate {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  opacity: 1;
}

.accordion .content {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  color: #333333;
}

#accordion-5 {
  margin-bottom: 48px;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'center the selected accordion'? How does that relate to scrolling the page? In your demo there's no scrolling as the page isn't tall enough..? This question needs more clarity regarding the goal before it can be answered.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Updated! Forgot to fill the paragraphs.

Comment: Did you save your changes? Nothing has been updated in the question

Comment: My mistake I only updated the codepen, question updated as well now.

Comment: Trying to do this while the elements are still opening/closing, probably makes rather little sense - will be hard to land on any consistent position with that. You could try and do it in the callback function for the `slideDown` animation - `$(this).parent().find(".content").slideDown(280, function() { this.closest('.accordion').scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "center"}); })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to do this while the elements are still opening/closing, probably makes rather little sense - will be hard to land on any consistent position with that. You could try and do it in the callback function for the slideDown animation:

```
$(this).parent().find(".content").slideDown(280, function() {
  this.closest('.accordion').scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth",
    block: "center"
  });
})
```

Comment: This works beautifully. Just to make sure I understand what's happening: 1. Slide down happens, then function is executed so that the closest accordion element to the header (ths) is scrolledIntoView, and we use "block: center" because by default it scrolls to the top of the element?

Comment: Yes, `this` inside the `slideDown` callback function will refer to the element that you called the method on - so one of the `.content` elements here in this case. The `closest` method traverses the DOM upwards, until it finds an element that matches the selector. (This is the DOM method `closest` used here, jQuery also has its own equivalent of that - syntax would be slightly different.) And yes, block:center is for the vertical alignment; default would be `start`.

Answer (score 1):

I changed your slideDown method and added a scrollTop animation for the selected item to the most center position of your screen. You maybe need some more items to test it properly.

```
const item = $(this)
$(this).parent().find(".content").slideDown(280, function () {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: item.offset().top + item.parent().height() / 2 - $(window).height() / 2
    })
});
```